# I have a problem with my SpamBot project, it doesn't do anything even though I followed the tutorial

Tags: python, tkinter, command, pyautogui

I am making a mini `SpamBot` project. When I press the button it doesn't work. I'm not sure what's the problem because I followed the tutorial and I tried everything and it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time


def spam():
    spam_word = e1.get()
    spam_quantity = e2.get()
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    count = 0
    time.sleep(10)
    while count <= (int(spam_quantity)):
        pyautogui.typewrite(spam_word)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        count += 1


# GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("SpamBot")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.configure(bg='SteelBlue1')

l1 = Label(root, text='Write a message that you want to send!', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid()
e1 = Entry(root).grid()
l2 = Label(root, text='Set the message quantity!', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid()
e2 = Entry(root).grid()
b1 = Button(root, text='Execute', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1', command=spam).grid()
l3 = Label(root, text='Made By HareXD', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `grid` function returns `None`, that's why the you're getting the error:

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

To fix it, you should replace the line:

```py
e1 = Entry(root).grid()
```

For this 2:

```py
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid()
```

And do the same with the `e2` entry.

The complete code would be:

```py
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time


def spam():
    spam_word = e1.get()
    spam_quantity = e2.get()
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    count = 0
    time.sleep(10)
    while count <= (int(spam_quantity)):
        pyautogui.typewrite(spam_word)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        count += 1


# GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("SpamBot")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.configure(bg='SteelBlue1')

l1 = Label(root, text='Write a message that you want to send!', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid()
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid()
l2 = Label(root, text='Set the message quantity!', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid()
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.grid()
b1 = Button(root, text='Execute', font='Consolas', command=spam,bg='SteelBlue1').grid()
l3 = Label(root, text='Made By HareXD', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Grid is to use row and column.

```
l1 = Label(root, text='Write a message that you want to send!', font='Consolas', bg='SteelBlue1').grid(row=0, column=0)
e1 = Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1)
```